# Confluence REST API - expanding page body when retrieving page by title

Tags: rest, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I'm accessing a Confluence page by its `title` using the latest REST API. To retrieve more details on certain fields, I'm passing the `expand` parameter (see [Confluence Docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-rest-api/confluence-rest-api-examples)):

```
https://xyz.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/?title=Architecture&spaceKey=XX&expand=body
```

or

```
https://xyz.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/?title=Architecture&spaceKey=XX&expand=body.view
```

But the results don't hold any information on the found page body.

Note, this is working fine with requests using a page id only. Using the title to retrieve the page is threaded similar to search results, hence the expand feature seems not to work the same. According to the documentation it should work as per my example. Am I missing something?

Comment: How about two requests: The first using title to find the ID and then the second to request by ID with the body expansion?

Comment: Thanks Adam, that's the current solution, but performance-wise it's not acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify which type of "body" you want in the expansion parameter.

In your case, something like this:

https://xyz.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/?title=Architecture&spaceKey=XX&expand=**body.view**

https://xyz.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/?title=Architecture&spaceKey=XX&expand=**body.export_view**

Possible values are:

- editor
- export_view
- anonymous_export_view
- view
- storage

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Indeed I tried a combination of various parameters, such as: `&spaceKey=XX&type=page&expand=space,body.view,version,container,page.body.view,results.body.view,page.body,results.body` - but the results always stays the same

Comment: Mmm... very strange, it works on my instances (v5.7 et v5.8.5): .../rest/api/content?spaceKey=DOC&title=Making%20a%20template&expand=body.export_view

Comment: Do you have a self-hosted instance or Confluence on demand (cloud hosted)? On the PAAS instances Atlassian has some different settings...

Comment: Yes, I have just tried it and it seems that the "title" query parameter doesn't work. I can do this:
/wiki/rest/api/content?spaceKey=DS1&expand=body.view,
but not this:
/wiki/rest/api/content?spaceKey=DS1&title="Demonstration%20Space"&expand=export.view. No results are returned like you. Seems to be a bug in the version 6.

Comment: You may try the Search REST API and CQL, it seems to work in my case:
**/wiki/rest/api/content/search?cql=space="DS1"%20and%20title="My%20First%20Page"&expand=body.view**

Comment: +1 for the `export_view`. This helped me to copy a page containing macros. I had a requirement to copy not the macros but the macro's result. `export_view` helped to achieve that. Is there a better way or that's the right way?